# Have I understood Database design correctly?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Have I understood db design correctly?

- A user can have one or multiple
  professions
- Each profession has multiple
  qualifications associated with it
- A user can have none or all of these
  qualifications.

Are there any improvements that should be made? simplicity should be maintained. I intend to shorten table and column names.

[image]

**UPDATE:** is this better?
[image]

Comment: Does users link to user_qualifications directly or is it via user_professions?

Comment: Do the bold field names correspond to the primary keys?

Comment: ar's comment is exactly what i was going to point to as well. Does your application allow a user to have a qualification even if he does not belong to a profession to which that qualification is associated with? If so, the design is fine. Otherwise, you could enforce that in your design as per ar's comment i.e linking qualifications via professions

Comment: yes bold field names correspond to the primary keys. no a user cant have a qualification unless he has a profession, due to the way the cms will be set up eg select profession then tick any relevant qualifications, so in that case I should also enforce that in the design as well. thanks.

Comment: why use surrogate primary keys for user_professions, user_qualifications etc when a composite key would better enforce integrity. For example what stops you adding the same qualification for the same user more than once ? a composite primary key (user_id, profession_id) would prevent this vs. having to create a business rule to enforce it in your design. In addition, if using engine=innodb the composite key would also be clustered on (user_id, profession_id) giving better performance and you'd have fewer indexes on those tables.

Comment: Surrogate primary keys are a matter of preference/tradeoffs. They can simplify front-end programming, and integrity can be enforced with an alternate unique composite index.  Both approaches are valid.

Comment: @Tim - agreed for front-end simplicity ?id=x but you'd lose the performance gain of clustered indexes plus add additional overhead for a constraining index/business rule etc.

Comment: Re keys. Whether or not you use surrogates The important point is that the database should implement ALL the keys required to keep the model correct. Your original diagram only showed one key per table - which appeared to be wrong because some "obvious" keys were not being enforced. I recommend that you use one of the standard diagram notations that allow multiple keys per table to be shown. That's the only effective way to do it in my

Comment: I agree with fOO. The value of surrogate primary keys in relationship tables is questionable.  It usually doesn't help with front end programming.

Comment: @dportas. Here's a case where distinguishing between a schematic diagram of a relational model and an ER diagram of an ER model would be useful. If foreign keys are used to implement relationships, then a schematic diagram is called for.  Other than this, I agree with your comment.

Comment: Have I understood correctly? with the updated diagram above?

Comment: You stil lhave to enforce the rule in the front end no matter what you keying strategy is. Adding a surrogtate key to a matching talbe often pays off as requirements change. Also the performance gain of clustered vs surrogate on sql server is goign to be negligable on an application where the guy is clearly new to database design. Its tiny and the larger the tables get the better a surrogate will get as the index will take up less space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "no a user cant have a qualification unless he has a profession" then maybe the user_qualification should link to both user_id and profession_id in user_professions to enforce that the combination user and profession is there before a qualification is set.

Comment: @davivid - Actually, i wouldnt do it as per the updated diagram you have shown. I personally would do it by having user_qualifications having a composite foreign key to profession_qualifications on columns profession_id + qualification_id. That is in addition to what i think is already a FK from User_qualifications to User_professions on user_id + profession_id. I dont quite understand how your updated design stops an invalid combination from being entered in user_qualifications.

Comment: Cool thanks, I decided to use a better software - Have I understood correctly? with the updated diagram above?

Answer (score 4):

No-no, do *not* shorten column or table names. There's nothing worse than `usr_qlfctns` or `prfsn2qlfctns`.

Otherwise, your design seems fine.

Comment: thanks, I originally was going to keep the names as they for readability, but my friend said how much of a pain it can be typing full length, and misspelling eg 'professions' and 'profesions' instead of example 'profs'

Comment: @davivd it can be worse trying to remember whether you called it prof, profs or prfsns :)

Comment: But it helps to spell the table name correctly :-) Qulaification [sic]

Comment: +1, it is virtually impossible to memorize shortened column names in a database with say 40 tables! I would also suggest using camleCase instead of underscores to separate words; I've always had to use the later, but it is such a pain typing out all those underscores!

Comment: your friend needs to be introduced to real DBA tools that do autocomplete and syntax checking for you, do NOT shorten names for the reasons your friend is saying. having the complete table name in foreign keys is very important for maintenance by your self later or other people. Also CamelCase is NOT appropriate, since SQL identifiers are case insensitive, stick with the _UNDERSCORE_ separators.

Comment: what DBA tools would you suggest?

Comment: @fuzzy, unless the database engine (lower/upper)case on identifier creation there´s no problem in using CamelCase. This is a problem some engines, other's simply compares with case insensivity. For logic design, makes no difference. Must have attention on physical structures design to not force the dba/developer to double quote everything.

Comment: for logical models, it doesn't matter, but for physical models it does matter case, the accepted practice is to name things all lower case with _ separators for max portability